# Optional parameter at the end but still getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optional-parameters

I have a very simple function in `C# V.4` in this function `page` is a optional parameter i.e. I normally call `mysite.com/product/PaginationOfProducts/20` but for some pagining control I have to call `mysite.com/product/PaginationOfProducts/20?page=2` but on building my solution I am getting the error that `optional parameters must appear after all required parameters`

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfProducts(int id = 0,  int ? page)
        {
// do something
}
```

I don't understand how VS is deciding `page` is not my optional parameter even though I am defining it as a `null-able int`

Comment: Are you using any specific routes? - you should have `url: .../{id}/{page}` with `page = UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Optional parameters are "optional" at runtime because you have supplied a value at compile time. Simply having a nullable as your final parameter does not make it optional as you're asking to the compiler to decide for you which is just bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give page a default value

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfProducts(int id = 0,  int? page = null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `int?` is `null` by default There is no need to set it to `null` again

Comment: @StephenMuecke: There is if you want to define it as an optional parameter.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, understand the difference between the default value of a variable, and the default value of an option parameter;
For `void Func() { int? page; }` page will be null, whereas `void Func(int? page)` page must be supplied when calling Func.

Comment: @ColinGrealy, I understand that, but this is a route issue and should be handle in the `RouteConfig` file (`page = UrlParameter.Optional`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the route config is no use if the code doesn't compile!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, the error says it all.
Change your method signature to

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfProducts( int? page, int id = 0)
```

Thus, make sure that the optional parameter appears after the required parameters.
page is not an optional parameter since it has no (explicit) default value, thus you cannot ommit it.

You could also change your method signature to

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfProducts( int id = 0, int? page = null)
```

By doing so, the page parameter is an optional parameter as well.